# Set Fabric runtime version

Tags: powershell, version, azure-service-fabric

Have multiple versions of Fabric runtimes on local machine (8.1, 8.2, and 9.0 series) which can be listed with:

```
Get-ServiceFabricRuntimeSupportedVersion
```

Have combed the Fabric documentation + web for anything about switching (changing) the SDK or Runtime version (effectively rolling back to an earlier installed version not the latest).  Nothing.  Anybody got an answer.  Stopped investigating after trying:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster
Unregister-ServiceFabricClusterPackage -Code -CodePackageVersion "9.0.1017.9590"
```

to back out version until I got to the one I want (8.2.1235.9590).  But that fail with:

```
Fabric version has not been registered
```

Assuming this concerns only the current Powershell context.  [Start-ServiceFabricClusterRollback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/start-servicefabricclusterrollback?view=azureservicefabricps) flops just like [Unregister-ServiceFabricClusterPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/unregister-servicefabricclusterpackage?view=azureservicefabricps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Control Panel choose Uninstall Programs and removed Fabric (6.0 SDK and Runtime). Restarted Windows (PC). Unclear if a restart is really necessary. Then opened the Web Platform Installer and through Spotlight searched for Fabric to click on Add. That put back 4.2.1235 of the SDK I needed. Done.

Answer (score 0):

This might be very unhelpful, but I think the Supported Runtime Version is just which runtimes does the PS scripts support, not something about the local cluster.

The runtime you have installed is the latest one, so if you want to use an old one you have to uninstall the latest and find the bits for the old runtime and install that.

I am however, not entirely certain! It might be possible to switch runtimes, though it seems unlikely.